# Although pc recognizes gpu, it uses a CPU in tensorflow-gpu

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gpu

I am using tensorflow-gpu.  I want to use GTX1070, but tensorflow-gpu uses my CPU.  I don't know　what to do.

I use CUDA 9.0 and CUDNN 7.1.4. My tensorflow-gpu version is 1.9.

After running this command on the official website

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
```

> 2018-07-30 10:53:43.369025: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141]
>   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
>   compiled to use: AVX2 2018-07-30 10:53:43.829922: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1392]
>   Found device 0 with properties: name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor:
>   1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.683 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 totalMemory:
>   8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.63GiB 2018-07-30 10:53:43.919043: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1392]
>   Found device 1 with properties: name: GeForce GTX 1050 major: 6 minor:
>   1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.455 pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0 totalMemory:
>   2.00GiB freeMemory: 1.60GiB 2018-07-30 10:53:43.926001: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1456]
>   Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci
>   bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1) with Cuda
>   multiprocessor count: 5. The minimum required count is 8. You can
>   adjust this requirement with the env var
>   TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT. 2018-07-30 10:53:43.934810: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1471]
>   Adding visible gpu devices: 0 2018-07-30 10:53:44.761551: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:952]
>   Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>   2018-07-30 10:53:44.765678: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:958]
>   0 1 2018-07-30 10:53:44.768363: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]
>   0:   N N 2018-07-30 10:53:44.771773: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]
>   1:   N N 2018-07-30 10:53:44.774913: I
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\co`enter code
>   here`re\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1084] Created TensorFlow
>   device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6395 MB
>   memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus
>   id: 0000`enter code here`:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

Comment: The message says its using your GeForce GTX 1070, while ignoring the GTX 1050, what's the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the log excerpt of your tensorflow engine - it uses GPU device 0

```
(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6395 MB memory) -> physical 
GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute 
capability: 6.1)
```

But refuses to use your GeForce GTX 1050. This is possible due to the Environment variable TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT which is seems set to 8.

Try to set it to value of 5 as advised in your log earlier:

`set TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT=5`

If you want to be sure which device is used - initialize the session with

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

You can read more on [Using GPUs tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu) docs page